# c++ assigning a string parameter to a string

Tags: c++, string, char, assign

I am trying to make a function that can change my account's pin number but having trouble finding the right way to assign the new one.

```
class Account;
class Account{

public:

    int accountNumber;
    char pin[5];
    double balance;
    void printInfo();
    void changeBalance(int n, char * p, double b);
    void changePin(int n, char * p, char * newPin);
};

void Account::changePin(int n, char * p, char * newPin)
{
    if((n == accountNumber) && (strcmp(p, pin) == 0))
    {
        //pin = newPin; //ERROR HERE
    }
}
```

am I supposed to not use an equal sign or use some function/pointer to assign a new pin?
I am fairly new to c++ so I am still trying to figure out how to properly declare/assign things.

Comment: hint: use strcpy or strncpy

Comment: Are you not using the C++ std::string class for a particular reason? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should copy the content of the point , try `strcpy(pin,newPin)`

Comment: strncpy is safer here!

Answer (score 1):

Never mind the class, the problem is how to assign a value to an array.

You can copy an array one element at a time:

```
for(unsigned int k=0; k<5; ++k)
  pin[k] = newPin[k];
```

You can take advantage of the fact that this is a *char* array, and use `strncpy`:

```
strncpy(pin, newPin, 5);
```

Or when you're tired of messing around with `char[]` you can look into `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
if(p!=NULL)
{
strcpy(this.pin,p);
}
```